# How to retrieve all fields from a ForeignKey after a filter query in django

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django

I have the following models using `django`

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Concert(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="action_concert")
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to display a list of Concert live, at the same time make sure that I get all the fields from `Action` table for each instance associated to it.

`concerts = Concert.objects.filter(is_live=True).values("id", "name")`

## current result => All the concerts live

This is the first step but i am stuck trying to join each instance of the list to it correspondent fields in Action.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: what is CoreAction model ? you did not show it you just showed Action model

Comment: @amadousow i just updated it, it was supposed to be `Action` only

Comment: try this `concerts = Concert.objects.filter(is_live=True).values("id", "name","action__name","action__slug","'action__created","action__updated")` with this you will get all the information in the Action model.

Comment: @amadousow thank you thats exactly that, didnt know you could still use `__` to access the other model, thanks